# portable Wi-Fi hotspot configuraiton

Tags: wi-fi, adb, wifi-hotspot

How it is possible to enable portable Wi-Fi hotspot from ADB shell or by editing some configuration files on Android Jelly Bean?
I need to do it interactive for automatic test server

Comment: What's wrong with Settings > More... (underneath Wi-fi) > Tethering and Portable hotspot > Portable Wifi hotspot?

Comment: I need to do it interactive (using ADB) - need it for automatic test server

Comment: @Dima See: [How to turn on the wi-fi hotspot using ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/173778/209414)

Answer (score 1):

If you have root on your phone, you can use [Wifi Tether](https://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/) for Root Users.  I have a Droid4 with Jellybean and got it working after installing the latest version.

For my Droid4, the following settings worked:

Device-Profile: Generic ICS/JB (wlan1)
Setup-Method: Netd-Ndc (master)

Comment: I need to enable Wi-Fi hotspot from ADB shell, not from GUI

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called FoxFi that lets you tether your phone's internet over bluetooth or wifi. There is no need for adb etc.

It is compatible with Jellybean because I use it too
Here is the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxfi

Comment: I need to do it interactive (using ADB) - need it for automatic test server

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger that using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm):

> WiFi Tether: Turn on sharing of the device's Internet connection via wifi.

You just need to pick a fitting trigger -- I picked [File Events](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/eh_index.html) for this example:

- **Condition:** File Events
- **Task:** WiFi Tether

So with that set up (specifying the parameters of course), you should be able to trigger your WiFi hotspot (aka "WiFi Tether", as the *Tasker* manual names it) by placing a file -- and trigger it off again by removing the file. Did not try that myself -- but that's how I understand it :)