# How to turn mobile hotspot off using ADB

Tags: adb

I need to turn the mobile hotspot off using ADB. I'm using various Samsung phones with Android 7 & 8.

I'm planning on opening the settings activity and using keyevents. I know the Mobile Hotspot and Tethering settings page is com.android.setting/.TetherSettings but beneath that there is a Mobile Hotspot page. Does anyone know how to open that page with ADB?

I'm open to alternative methods of turning mobile hotspot on and off with ADB.

Suggested solution in [How to turn on the wi-fi hotspot using ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173709/how-to-turn-on-the-wi-fi-hotspot-using-adb) does not work for the phones I've got.

On Android 7 and earlier you can achieve the desired result by turning on Wifi (which automatically disables the hotspot) and then turning Wifi off again. However Android 8 thwarts this by popping up a warning dialog which has to be dismissed.