# adb shell input key event : perform a toggle button on off action

Tags: adb, shell, magisk, input-methods, android-studio

**Questions**

- How do   I in `Android 10` toggle  on /off the `hotspot` using adb
- `Su` switch on / off for `shell`- How do I turn on Magisk manager &&  goto security options  && there  turn on / off the option to grant `su to  shell.` (see attached screenshot ) using `adb`

This question is here since it pertains to programabiliy  of  Android not an admin question.

So far

Using [this guide](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173709/how-to-turn-on-the-wi-fi-hotspot-using-adb) I can using this commmand come to the point of  simulating the action of entering hotspot settings

```
  adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.TetherSettings
```

Hoever after that i am left with a situation that needs to perform a `toggle switch` on to turn on my Hostpot and in case of `Magisk` Manager I Need to get inside and then go to security options and turn off `Su` for `Shell` . How can above both be accomplished

[image: Hotspot toggle switch]

[image: Magisk Manager Security options]

Comment: Have you tried Macrodroid

Comment: hadnt heard that ...sounds interesting..will give it a shot. I'd imagine there'd be a simple way to simulate `toggle on hotspot` and some activity of `magisk manager` that can  be called via `adb`. I am not an Android dev but now feel like i should open a few things under the hood